# How to stop a form from loading if a particular condition is not met?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am on VB.NET and when the form is loading it checks if a file exists or not. If the file is found then it continues to load else it gives an error box and quits.

Something like

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim file As FileStream = New FileStream("target.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
'code to stop form loading goes here.
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: To check if the file exists, you should use `If IO.File.Exists("target.txt")` as explained in @jonathana's answer. And in order to close the form, you can simply call `Me.Close()`. However, if this form is opened by another form/method, you should check if the file exists before you load the form, if it's there, go on and load the form; if not, do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim file As FileStream = New FileStream("target.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        'the rest of your "load" code goes here...
    Catch ex As System.IO.FileNotFoundException
        MessageBox.Show("File not found", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

It will show a `MessageBox` and close the form if the file is not found.